# How to remove dependency from EntityFrameworkCore 3 in ASP.NET core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My EF-Core database access layer and ASP.NET Core application are in different projects. I am trying to wire-up Database access layer to Web application and come with code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));

    services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext, DatabaseContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IPlanService, PlanService>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Unfortunately, this adds a dependency on the EntityFrameworkCore library. How to move DI wire-up outside Web application into the Database project?

I was using a similar approach in ASP.NET MVC(not Core) project with Unity DI, there was `UnityContainerExtension` class for that. My old example

DI wire-up in the database layer

```
 public class SharedUnityRegistry : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        private readonly Func<Type, LifetimeManager> _lifeTimeManager;

        public SharedUnityRegistry(Func<Type, LifetimeManager> lifetimeManager)
        {
            _lifeTimeManager = lifetimeManager;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Container.RegisterTypes(
                AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(DatabaseContext).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
                WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
                WithName.Default,
                _lifeTimeManager);            
        }
    }
```

DI Wire-up in ASP.NET web project, no dependency from EF

```
  UnityContainer.AddExtension(new SharedUnityRegistry(lifetimeManager => new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()));
```

Comment: The question is self-contradictory: DbContext is provided by EF Core. You can't remove the library that defines the class you want to use. Are you asking how to remove *your* library's raw configuration code from Startup.cs perhaps? Add your own `AddMyLibrary()`, `UseMyLibrary()` extension methods in your assembly and call them from Startup.cs

Comment: If you want to register *all* DbContexts in all assemblies, you can do so with code similar to what you used with Unity - get all assemblies, then all types in the assemblies that inherit from `DbContext` and register them. Just don't use `services.AddScoped<DbContext, DatabaseContext>();`: First, `DbContext` is the base class for *all* contexts and that line says there's only one DbContext implementation. Second, `AddDbContext` already registers the context as scoped

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated my question to not depend on DbContext introducing such inheritance  DatabaseContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext. So the question appears open, how to move injection out of web project, is that possible using build-in DI?

Comment: the Unity code doesn't remove any dependencies. It registers all types derived from a specific type. This is done using Reflection, you can do the same in .NET Core 3.1. At least in 3.0, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, get the derived types and register them. Or you can wire up Unitiy and .NET Core DI and use the Unity code directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just forget about my provided old code, what I need is to move these two methods out of web project services.AddDbContext and services.AddScoped to remove dependency from EF-Core. There should be some kind of DI registration class where I could move all wire up to other projects.

Comment: I already explained you can just create an extension method in your assembly and call it from Startup. That's how even Microsoft's extensions work. `AddAuthentication` is an extension method in the appropriate assembly, not a method of `IServicesCollection` or `IConfiguration`. I suppose that's what you mean by `move all wire up to other projects`. Instead of `UnityContainerExtension`, add an extension method

Comment: As for dynamic context registration, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain
.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes())
.Where(type => typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(type))` will get you all DbContexts in the entire application. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().....` will get the DbContexts only for the current assembly. You can loop over them and register them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How I didn't come with an idea about Extension Methods :) Just trying to solve simple things in a complex way. Thank you!

Comment: _Why_ do you want this? If your library uses Entity Framework, then the Entity Framework assembly must be present in the application directory. If you don't want to reference it directly (and **why not?**), you're going to hide it using reflection magic without any obvious benefit, while adding useless complexity.

Comment: @CodeCaster the OP meant how to move the registration to the assemblies instead of `Startup`

Comment: @Panagiotis _"Unfortunately, this adds a dependency on the EntityFrameworkCore library"_ seems to be their real problem with this.

Comment: @CodeCaster you have to read the entire comment thread. For people jumping from (the rather old) Unity model to .NET Core's style, it's easy to assume there's some magic behind the `Add` and `Use` methods.

Comment: @CodeCaster I got the impression that the question was something else from the start, which is why I persisted in the thread. Looks I guessed correctly this time: `How I didn't come with an idea about Extension Methods :) Just trying to solve simple things in a complex way.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an extension method for this and place it in your database project. But you still need to have a reference to your database project.

Database project:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection UseMyDatabase(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        return services;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.UseMyDatabase(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this project](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner) I've solved this issue like this:

- Create interface [IStartupRegistrator](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Core/IStartupRegistrator.cs) which is being called during application startup. This allows satellite assemblies to register their services, without having the need to decide in startup itself.
- Implement [EF data access](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF) layer which is NOT aware of the underlying DB
- Create a dedicated data context (with migrations) for supported DBs. In my case [MsSql](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.MsSql), [Sqlite](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.Sqlite) and [in memory](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.InMemory) (used for unit tests). The DB to use is being set in the app settings and each DB provider decides if it is him having to register himself; e.g. [here](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/master/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.InMemory/StartupRegistrator.cs#L24)

Note that only projects in the namespace `Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess` reference EF core. For the record: I wasn't able to use asp.net identity, because of this.